# application architecture mvc4 ef5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am planning for one project to develop an application using MVC4, EF5 and Web Api. Please anyone suggest how we to design project in different layer. Web using MVC4 and Data Layer using EF5/Repository pattern and Web Api for JQuery access.

Comment: Why do you plan on using Web API for jquery access? Why not just reference the jquery file from the page?

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using the layers shown in the following diagram.

[image: Architecture Layers in an MVC App]

I added the [Unit of Work Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx) which handles transactions across multiple Repositories. And I also use an application or domain layer that handles all of the business logic. When you use an domain layer then your Web API just becomes a thin layer that handles the transport and serialization of objects to remote clients such as your web client (i.e. web browser). The web client uses jQuery Ajax to communicate with the Web API. The MVC controller is used to render Views (Your HTML, CSS and JavaScript).  The model part of the MVC in this architecture is your application / domain layer. Note that this architecture also works will with [Single Page Applications (SPAs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin, it's realy valuable information for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin, very interesting and useful answer, very clear, thanks. Just one question. When using the Web API and trying to follow your architecture flow, please tell me if I understood it well: Request on the client (via AJAX) => Controller => ASP.NET Web API => Application layer => UoW => Repository => EF => DB. So now, the response: DB => EF => Repo => UoW => Application layer => ASP.NET Web API => Controller (populate the view or return json to the client) => Change on client (page/view/jquery, etc). Thanks.

Comment: It is unusual to see a question to an answer as another answer. You probably should have done this as a comment and the people who police this site will probably correct you. That being said, you are close but an AJAX request does not go directly to the Controller, it goes directly to the Web API. In a SPA the only time the Controller is used is to render the initial page.  After the initial page is rendered the web client makes AJAX requests to the Web API returning JSON that is used to update the View, preferably by using something like KnockoutJS which handles a MVVM engine on your client.

Comment: Kevin, I'm terribly sorry about where my answer appears, other times I've commented I had the option to "add a comment" (like now!) but before it appeared just the possibility to add the answer. Just one question more, that first time controller is uses to render the initial page, does it make the data request to the Web API or directly to the Application Layer? Thank you and sorry again.

Comment: You could go either way and the design decision probably should consider the layout of the page and the user experience. I tend to just have the initial page be just the skeleton of the layout and use the Web API to fill in the details after the initial load. This way the user sees a quick rendering of the initial page layout and can watch the details fill in asynchronously with some indicator letting the user know that these detail areas are still rendering.